# Android maps v2: MyLocation-Button only works with GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I have a question about working with the built-in "my location"-button. In my setup I have

`mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

So, the button is rendered on the map and when the GPS is turned on, it works like a charm. When GPS is turned off, it doesn't work anymore. Is it standard behavior of the "my location"-button to work only when GPS is enabled?

I would like to show the rough position on the map, even GPS is disabled. Do I have to use the LocationManager to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: If GPS is turned off, how would it get the location?

Comment: By using the "NETWORK" mode. The position would not be as precise as a position estimated by GPS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Android Maps API V2, you can use the [`LocationSource`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) and [`LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener) to pass in your own location updates and control the location that is shown on the map.

For example, you can listen to `GPS_PROVIDER` or `NETWORK_PROVIDER` location updates via a normal [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html), and pass these locations to the `LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener`.  Whatever you pass in is what gets shown on the map.

First, declare an `OnLocationChangedListener` object in your `Activity`:

```
private OnLocationChangedListener mListener; //Used to update the map with new location
```

Then, implement LocationSource for your activity, something like:

`public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity implements LocationSource {`

In `onCreate()`, set up the `LocationSource` for this `Activity` when you're setting up the Map object:

```
...
// Show the location on the map
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
// Set location source
mMap.setLocationSource(this);
...
```

Then, add the methods required for the `LocationSource` interface:

```
/**
 * Maps V2 Location updates
 */
@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;       
}

/**
 * Maps V2 Location updates
 */
@Override
public void deactivate() {
     mListener = null;      
}
```

The final part is passing in the location updates from a normal `LocationListener` to the `Activity` implementing the `LocationSource`:

```
//Update real-time location on map
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

If you're listening to the `GPS_PROVIDER` and passing locations from this provider into the `mListener.onLocationChanged()` method, and you turn off GPS, if you don't take any further actions with the `LocationSource`, the most recent GPS location will remain on the screen.  At this point you can listen to the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and pass these location updates to the `mListener.onLocationChanged()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache the last known location and show it when you dont have gps on or gps not available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must request for location updates. Even if you don't use the incoming location in your code, the blue dot appears.